# Lightweight Render Pipeline messes the textures of the objects

Tags: unity-game-engine, rendering, textures, unity3d-shaders

I was working on one of Unity's tutorial projects(the cute nightmare survival one) and wanted to add something cool using Lightweight RP. But upgrading to Lightweight RP messed up my textures. Apart from turning to everything pink when I go Edit>Render Pipeline>Lightweight RP>Upgrade Project Materials....; some of the objects still remain pink and when I manually set their shader the original texture is lost. I am currently using Unity 2019.2.

Before using Lightweight RP
[image]

After using Lightweight RP
[image]

These are the options I am getting for my shaders. Selected the 'lit' option.
[image]

Also it would be really helpful to do something about the lighting as after LRP it gets really dull and also I have an in game option for setting the brightness of the game which becomes useless after upgrading.

Answer (score 1):

You can no longer use the standard shader. What I did was open my 3D model in blender and redue my materials. If you cant do that I think you can use the render pipline shaders instead of the standard

Comment: I did use the render pipeline shaders. In shaders I did LRP>Lit.

Comment: I just upgraded to HDRP and used the lit shader and it fixed the issue no problem. Can you attatch a screen shot of the object in the inspector?

Comment: Edited the question and added an ss of the options I am getting for my shaders.

Comment: Well first off change your base map color to pure white. Changing mine to a grayish color makes my character look like yours

Comment: Changing base map color didn't work. But what I noticed was that base map texture was empty. So added a texture to it and it kinda worked.

Comment: And also the normal mapped texture is all blue. Is it supposed to be like that?
https://imgur.com/v7KqrkH

Comment: Well Ive tried looking into this issue for you. Id say they upgraded correctly considering your object isnt pink. The issue could be that LWRP shaders use a defualt property called "_BaseMap" which is automatically a gray color. Do you know how to use shader graph to create custom shaders? Replace the "_BaseMap" with your texture at runtime and this might solve your issue. The only other thing I can think of is that your camera or post processing effects are messing up your scene. Try looking into those and changing settings. Im sorry I cant be more help. Im not the most skilled at shaders :(

Comment: Its all good man because of that basemap thing I am getting the previous textures back(almost). Kudos to that. What seems to be the problem now is I think the lightings.

Comment: btw is HDRP better than LWRP?

Comment: Yes and HDRP uses high dynamic range for one. LWRP is better fit for mobile games for example. If youre aiming for performance and still want something to look good then use LWRP. If youre aiming for High end graphics then use HDRP.

Comment: You can still use HDRP if youre making a PC game that doesnt necessarily have "AAA Graphics". But things like volumetric fog amd procedual skyboxes can take a lot of performance power compared to a LWRP preset which doesnt have the option for these features I believe

Comment: I see Great help. Thanks